# Interpolation not working properly inside mat-form-field for mat-error

Tags: angular-material, customvalidator

I am validating username with custom validation in angular material
Following is my code

```
 <mat-form-field>
          <input id="Username" required name="Username" [(ngModel)]="employee.Username" type="text" matInput
            #Username="ngModel" (focusout)="ValidateUsername($event.target.value)" placeholder="Username">
            <mat-error *ngIf="isNotValidUsername">Username already exist</mat-error>
          <mat-error *ngIf="Username.errors?.required && Username.touched">Required</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
```

Problem is "Username already exist" error not showing.
If i write this error line code outside mat-form-field then it worked. And also if Required error fired then it also show "Username already exist" error. But it alone inside mat-form-field tag not working. What i am doing wrong? How can i show it?

Comment: Pls provide your validation code!

Comment: ValidateUsername(username) {
    this.employeeService.ValidateUsername(username).subscribe((res:boolean) => {
      this.isNotValidUsername = res;
    })   
  }

Comment: When you debug your code will the *ValidateUsername* function get called?

Comment: yes it called and also saved its response in "this.isNotValidUsername" variable. When i placed " <mat-error *ngIf="isNotValidUsername">" tag outside mat-form-field tag then it shows error. Otherwise its not visible.

Answer (score 0):

mat-error won't show errors if the control is valid. You can use the error state matcher to set an invalid state to the input. The following post includes how it is implemented in a password validation form group.

https://stackblitz.com/angular/brleoyyorkap?file=app%2Finput-error-state-matcher-example.ts